# UnityAds in iOS using wrong game id, and not working

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ads, unityads

I am using UnityAds in my mobile game, to show a banner and a rewarded video.
In the editor and in Andorid works fine.

However for iOS  it doesn't work, i took the logs and i noticed that for iOS is using my android gameid, this i have no idea where it comes from, i searched every file in my project, i never reference the android gameid, just the iOS one.
So it is clearing taking the id not from my initialization but from some sort of cache, anybody has an idea where is taking the gameid from? thanks

Btw
I am using Advertisement package from package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can open manually `Project Folder\ProjectSettings\UnityConnectSettings.asset` in text or code editor, then find

```
UnityAdsSettings:
  m_Enabled: 0
  m_InitializeOnStartup: 1
  m_TestMode: 0
  m_IosGameId: <---- THIS ONE
  m_AndroidGameId: 
  m_GameIds: {}
  m_GameId:
```

and edit it